# Can't track down possible import/export error - React/ES6 modules

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, import, export

I've created a wrapper around a react package (react-datepicker) in order to have a cohesive datepicker across products on my team. I have written the wrapper where I can pass in a custom input component to be rendered. I have tested it and it works in Storybook.

I am now trying to tie this wrapper into a Rails app. I have a repo that builds components that can be inserted into the Rails application (works for other components).

When trying to render the component, I get the following error:

```
Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check your code at index.js:8.
    in DatePicker (at renderComponent.js:5)
```

I have scoured SO and the answer *seems* to be that there is a likelihood that I have possibly done an import of a named export without `{}` or imported a default export with `{}`.

I've triple checked my code and cannot find where this may be happening.

The following is my code for the wrapper.

**FVDatePicker.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker'
import 'react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css'
import FVPicker from './FVDatePickerStyles'

class FVDatePicker extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      selectedDate: ''
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ selectedDate: this.props.date || new Date() })
  }

  changeDateValue = selectedDate => {
    this.setState({ selectedDate })
  }

  render() {
    // This check and subsequent throw is because PropTypes
    // doesn't stop the execution of the component
    if (!this.props.customInput) {
      throw "'customInput' prop is required"
    }

    return (
      <FVPicker className="FVDatePicker">
        <DatePicker
          customInput={this.props.customInput}
          selected={this.state.selectedDate}
          onChange={date => this.changeDateValue(date)}
          dateFormat={this.props.dateFormat || 'MM/dd/yyyy'}
        />
      </FVPicker>
    )
  }
}

FVDatePicker.propTypes = {
  customInput: PropTypes.node.isRequired
}

export default FVDatePicker
```

**The corresponding styles FVDatePickerStyles.js *uses react-emotion***

```
import styled from 'react-emotion'
import DT from 'design-tokens/src/design-tokens'

const FVPicker = styled.div/* css */ `
  display: inline-block;

  // Other styles but leaving out for the sake of brevity

`

export default FVPicker
```

The above code is then rolled up into `dist/index.js`

In my renderable application, here is the code.

**componentName/index.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import FVDatePicker from 'fv-datepicker'
import renderComponent from '../../utils/renderComponent'
import CustomDatePickerInput from './CustomDatePickerInput'

const DatePicker = () => {
  return (
    <FVDatePicker
      date=""
      inputName="start-time"
      dateFormat="yyyy/MM/dd"
      customInput={<CustomDatePickerInput />}
    />
  )
}

window.DatePicker = renderComponent(DatePicker)
export default DatePicker
```

`FVDatePicker` comes from node_modules as it's in the `package.json`

And this is the renderComponent that is referenced in the above file:

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'

const renderComponent = Component => (element, props = {}) =>
  render(<Component {...props} />, element)

export default renderComponent
```

The expected result should be that my component should render within the rails application, but throws the above listed error (I'll add again here):

```
Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check your code at index.js:8.
    in DatePicker (at renderComponent.js:5)
```

Am I missing something with the import/exports? Or doing something else wrong?

Comment: is FVDatePicker  a default import or a named import ? try import {FVDatePicker } from 'fv-datepicker'

Comment: @PouyaAtaei , thank you. That made it work! Now I just need to figure out why the CSS from the package I'm wrapping, `import 'react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css'`, isn't working. Seems weird that the CSS is totally not there. I wonder if it's a tree shaking issue.

Comment: are you sure that your CSS file is there? and besides, once all the problems are solved let me know and i'll post an answer... cheers

Comment: @PouyaAtaei, Yep, the CSS was there. I figured out the issue. It was the PostCss plugin for rollup. The modules flag was set to true and it was hashing my CSS selectors causing the CSS to not bind to the elements. Once I removed `{modules: true` it worked as planned. Thanks for the help. We're good here!

Comment: Would you mind marking my answer as a solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is **FVDatePicker** a **default import** or a **named import** ? try

```
import { FVDatePicker } from 'fv-datepicker'
```

Those kind of react errors usually occur when imports are wrong, and it's easily to overlook that...